# I could not debug using goclipse plugin, windows environment

Tags: eclipse, debugging, go, goclipse

I could not debug using goclipse plugin, it was asking about gdb debugger then I downloaded the binary ver. 7.6 but now it is giving me "Source Not found"..

As suggest from many posts, I tried to build the program before going to start debugging but still it is giving me the same thing.

below is a secreenshot[image]

even I found some guys were saying is to specify the working directory in configuration as "other" but still giving me the same error

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

finally, I fixed the issue by using the "gdb" distributed within [liteide](http://code.google.com/p/liteide) package. you could reference it from "Window | Preferences"